# PHP 5.3 dynamic array broken

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I have a legacy system that has switched to running PHP 5.3. An issue that has appeared is with the code designed to edit dynamically produced values in a table. The editinvoice array has no value. Any ideas?

```
//Line Item x:<input type="text" name="editinvoice[lineitem_text_x]">
//Value x:<input type="text"    name="editinvoice[lineitem_amount_x]">

//edit values in the invoice table
$sqldata = array();
foreach   ($_POST['editinvoice'] AS $k => $v)
{
    $sqldata[] = "$k = '$v'";
}
$sql = "UPDATE db.invoices SET ".implode(',', $sqldata)." WHERE (booking_id = '$booking_id') LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($sql);
```

I'm aware mysql is depreciated, however, no resources to rewrite the system and it's on an intranet so no SQL injection worries.

Comment: try to dump `$sqldata` and `$sql`. what values they has? Try to directly run your output of `echo $sql` in the mysql. What is it says?

Comment: At first glance I don't see any compatibility issues. Maybe you didn't enable the `mysql` extension?

Comment: I'm going to bet that (a) the problem is that in PHP 5.3 `magic_quotes_gpc` is turned off, and (b) you have a huge SQL injection hole that should be your main concern.

Comment: this code runs on everypage to get around depreciation of magic_quotes. 
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
  $_POST[$key] = addslashes($val);
}

Comment: @lolka_bolka - $sql_data has no value

Comment: And what `var_dump($_POST)` says?

Comment: @lolka_bolka - value for ["editinvoice"]=> NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code implies that you expect `$_POST['editinvoice']` to be an array. But you said that you added somewhere as a substitution for `magic_quotes_gpc` a

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    $_POST[$key] = addslashes($val);
}
```

So guess what happened there with the array `$_POST['editinvoice']`?

```
<?php

$expected = array("foo" => "bar");
$_POST["editinvoice"] = addslashes($expected);
assert ($expected == $_POST["editinvoice"]); // it's NULL
```

> Warning: addslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string…
>   PHP Warning:  assert(): Assertion failed

You might find such a warning in your error log as well.

Your code relies on `magic_quotes_gpc=on`. So turn it on again and remove that broken workaround. You can still figure out a workaround when you update to >=PHP-5.4.